# How to use FCM with Bazel in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, bazel

I have been trying to implement Firebase with Bazel in Android Studio and my Application is building successfully by running `bazel build myapp` but Firebase Services are not starting.I am getting `FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful`. Here is my [WORKSPACE](https://pastebin.com/X6MpJaVC) and [BUILD](https://pastebin.com/X5h6bPf6) files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was able to implement it successfully. Refer to my [Github](https://github.com/akabravo97/BazelWithFirebaeMessagingService) repository.

Comment: Please attribute the source of this GitHub repository: https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/bazel-discuss/rizq2Es-Sjw/eogwixNrEQAJ